# Why is pywinauto only clicking the button when I'm looking?

Tags: python, python-2.x, pywinauto

I'm trying to have Windows Task Scheduler automate an application with [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/) while I'm logged in, but the computer is switched to a different user.  I currently have:

```
from time import sleep
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='program.exe')
sleep(5)
if 'System Administration' in app.top_window().window_text():
    app.top_window().SignOut.click()
    sleep(5)
    app.top_window().print_control_identifiers(filename='controls.txt')
```

At which point, controls.txt has:

```
Control Identifiers:


Dialog - 'System Administration - V6.0.3'    (L448, T158, R1471, B922)
[u'System Administration - V6.0.31', u'System Administration - V6.0.30', u'System Administration - V6.0.3', u'System Administration - V6.0.3Dialog', u'Dialog']
child_window(title="System Administration - V6.0.3", control_type="Window")

   | 
...
   | 
   | Button - 'Sign out'    (L980, T399, R1120, B444)
   | ['Button8', u'Sign out', u'Sign outButton']
   | child_window(title="Sign out", control_type="Button")

   |
```

Indicating that the 'Sign out' button hasn't been clicked, because this should now be the next set of menus.  What has me really confused, though, is that if I'm logged in and watching the application, then everything behaves correctly: the button is clicked and the application goes to the next set of menus.

Other things I've tried:

`pywinauto.actionlogger.enable()` results in:

```
2018-05-06 16:15:15,145;INFO
Invoked button "Sign out"
```

(but still doesn't click the button)

`app.top_window().SignOut.click_input()` results in:

```
2018-05-07 12:00:11,730;ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.top_window().SignOut.click_input()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 671, in click_input
    key_down=key_down, key_up=key_up)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\mouse.py", line 125, in _perform_click_input
    win32api.SetCursorPos((coords[0], coords[1]))
error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

I don't know what that means.  Having the Task Scheduler "Run with highest privileges" results in:

```
2018-05-08 08:45:05,908;ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='program.exe')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 955, in connect
    self.__warn_incorrect_bitness()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1028, in __warn_incorrect_bitness
    if self.backend.name == 'win32' and self.is64bit() != is_x64_Python():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1043, in is64bit
    return handleprops.is64bitprocess(self.process)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\handleprops.py", line 172, in is64bitprocess
    phndl = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, 0, process_id)
error: (5, 'OpenProcess', 'Access is denied.')
```

(This is also confusing because Python and the program are both 32 bit.)

How can I get pywinauto to click the button when I've switched to a different user account?

Answer (score 1):

When Windows user is locked, you have no active desktop. So any GUI automation tool won’t work. This is OS restriction. You should have VM or remote machine with RDP in windowed mode (non-minimized). VNC server software can replace RDP with disconnection possibility keeping an active desktop all the time (like VNC server). Or special mstsc setting should be set to allow minimizing.

This SetCursorPos issue could be seen for UAC security confirmation as well. This is by OS design also.

P.S. Make sure running script as Administrator. Currently such problems are silent, but 0.6.5 will warn about insufficient privileges.

Comment: (I'm finally getting back to this.)  The strange thing is, there's a computer in my office.  I can schedule this script on that computer and switch to a different user, and the script runs fine.  Any other computer (or if I lock my account instead of switching to a different one), and the script doesn't work.  I can't figure out what makes that computer different (and worry that whatever makes it different will stop, so that the script stops working).  Any guesses?